# Exclude a link from nivo lightbox

Tags: jquery, lightbox, nivo-slider

I am using nivo lightbox plugin. It is working good. But when I have added my youtube channel link to my social icons, it is also opening my channel link in the lightbox. How can I get rid of it?

Here is the nivo lightbox code I am using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').nivoLightbox();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment there may be an alternative to the accepted answer:

> There is a lot of links in my site. It will be hard to add a class in
>   every link

It may be easier for you to exclude your youtube link if there is a specific class associated with it like `socialClass` in the example below:

```
<a href="http://youtube.com/yourchannel" class="socialClass">My Youtube Channel Link</a>
```

You can use the jQuery [`.not()` function](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude the `.socialClass` links specifically:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').not('.socialClass').nivoLightbox();
});
```

---

I still recommend you go with the other answer to continue to decorate your lightbox links with an appropriate `class=nivolightbox` but you should also be aware of the .not() function and when/where to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Put class of the links with lightbox...

Example:

```
<a href="img/1.jpg" class="nivolightbox">something</a>
<a href="img/2.jpg" class="nivolightbox">something</a>
```

and lightbox code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.nivolightbox').nivoLightbox();
});
```

Comment: There is a lot of links in my site. It will be hard to add a class in every link

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nivolightbox > a').nivoLightbox();
});

<div id="nivolightbox">
 <a href="img/1.jpg">something</a>
 <a href="img/2.jpg">something</a>
</div>